# C# getting values from Dictionary<string, List<object>>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a question about how to get values from my `Dictionary<string, List<object>>`, I tried all examples which I found in google, but still can't get something readable value.....

so, here is the code:

```
List<object> listValues = new List<object>();
listValues.Add(risk);
listValues.Add(validFrom);
listValues.Add(effectiveDate);

Dictionary<string, List<object>> dic = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();
dic.Add(nameOfInsuredObject, listValues);

foreach (object value in dic.Values)
{
  System.Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

I can get key from dictionary, but with getting value I am stucked now....
And here is the result of this code:

```
Key => testInsObj
Values => System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]
```

So can anyone help me with it? I am new in C#, so maybe this is easy questions for others....

Comment: Seems like you should create a custom type instead `List<object>` And what is the problem with getting the value? it seems fine

Comment: What is your expected output? i.e. What do you consider "readable"? The dictionary value is a list. If you want the values from the list, iterate through the list and print the values.

Comment: You know that each `value` in `dic.Values` in a list of objects - `List<object>`? So what should a `.ToString()` of a `List<object>` be in your imagination?

Comment: @itsme86 but if I want to get values from dictionary not from list? or its equals?

Comment: Values is showing the result of `.ToString()` which is often the name of the object's type. If you want something else you can compute a different string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for writing values of the list this way:

```
foreach (var value in dic.Values)
{
    value.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}
```

In fact each element of the Dictionary is `<string, List<Object>>`. So, when you want to write `Value` part of the pair to console, you need a for loop to write each element of the `List<object>`.

Comment: Just for your information `value.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);` is equivalent to `value.ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x));` if it's more readable for you :)

Comment: it is also equivliant to `foreach(var x in value) { Console.WriteLine(x); }` if the `.ForEach` method is confusing you.

Answer (score 1):

It is confusing for new C# users, how to access the dictionary.

When you do a `foreach` on the dictionary, you get a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`. Now this `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`, has 2 properties `KeyValuePair.Key` and `KeyValuePair.Value`, representing the `Key` and `Value` stored in the dictionary.

Also, the `Value` in your case is a `List<T>`, which means doing a `Console.WriteLine` on it will not print the whole `List<T>` (as some people expect), but just some reference string. You will have to "loop" over the list to print individual elements. Needless to say, depending on what you want to do with the element in the `List<T>`, you can use `LINQ` or some other common C# idiom.

```
foreach (var value in dic) {
    Console.WriteLine(value.Key);
    foreach (var item in value.Value)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```